# HTML random number to text

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have this code. Which when you press "RUN" It prints a random number. I need some help (not sure where to start) to when it prints a random number it also prints text associated with that number. Example if it generates any number from 1-5 it will say "Hello" and if it generates 7 it will say "Wassup". Any help is appreciated.

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function RandomID() {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        document.getElementById('id').value = rnd;
   }
    </script>
<button class="button"onclick="RandomID();" style="font-family: sans-serif;">RUN</button>
<input class="input" type="text" id="id" name="id" size="3" readonly />
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9dcp2t4/

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn what an if statement is. Google JavaScript Conditions and study up

Comment: Put the messages in an array, then use the random number as the index of the array.

Comment: @Ofcdan it's not a matter of "not knowing as much as other people". Every question asked _by definition_ comes from exactly that perspective. You, however, are asking an incredibly basic question that is answered as part of the very beginning of learning pretty much any programming language. Moreover, you have not shown any of your effort of trying to solve it. You have essentially asked people to write the code for you. If you look at the text associated with downvoting, your question covers both "not show any research effort" and  "not useful".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use an [`if..else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement:

```js
function RandomID() {
  var value;
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

  if (rnd === 7)
    value = "Wassup";
  else if (rnd <= 5)
    value = "Hello";
  else
    value = rnd;

  document.getElementById('id').value = value;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="RandomID();" style="font-family: sans-serif;">RUN</button>
<input class="input" type="text" id="id" name="id" size="3" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside an `if` statement, you could use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

> ```
> condition ? expr1 : expr2
> ```

```js
function RandomID() {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    document.getElementById('id').value = rnd;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = rnd >= 1 && rnd <= 5 ? 'Hello' : rnd === 7 ? 'Wassup' :  '';
}
```

```html
<button class="button"onclick="RandomID();" style="font-family: sans-serif;">RUN</button>
<input class="input" type="text" id="id" name="id" size="3" readonly />
<span id="out"></span>
```